# What is the vertical equivalent of CSS font-kerning?

Tags: css, text, fonts, vertical-alignment, font-size

I have a font that is misaligned since the baseline is below `y`, `g`, `j`, etc. as opposed to regular baseline.

I've tried messing around with a few properties (`line-height`, `height`, `display: inline-block`, `vertical-align`: `text-top`) but can't get the font as far centered as it should be.

Is there a CSS equivalent of kerning, but in a vertical direction? Is there another way to uniformly fix this font via CSS?

Comment: Can you show an example that you have tried? The appropriate word would be "leading" in print terms, and the "line-height" property usually takes care of this unless you have something overriding it.

Comment: @DerekGutierrez I think that's technically the answer: "leading" and that CSS only supports `line-height`. In my case, it seems the correct answer (as usually with CSS) is to create a wrapper, and pad that wrapper asymmetrically so the entire text block shifts up/down. I did use `line-height: 100%` to crop the font span, but that shouldn't be necessary. Just create a wrapper and pad it asymmetrically.

Comment: Could you please share the font?

Comment: @neaumusic that is a good solution. Unfortunately all fonts have different baselines and line heights by default, I run into that issue quite often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very old question, but the solution I ended up using (as with most CSS) was to create a wrapper and pad asymmetrically, therefore raising the apparent baseline.

The main use-case was with headers with large `border-radius` causing slight (visual) vertical mis-alignment.